# Website for Stirlitz Jokes?

Tags: resources

Is there a website for Stirlitz jokes?

Comment: There are plenty of them - just google "анекдоты про штирлица".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some pun jokes, try for example [this](http://www.wwk.kiev.ua/182.html) or [this](http://www.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/o.m.matushansky/stirlitz.html).